# Determine the dynamic IP address of a remote computer in order to SSH

Tags: ip-address, remote-access

I will be setting up a computer with SSH and VNC servers in order to access it remotely since I won't have physical access. If the IP address changes how can I track this? The first idea that comes to mind is to write a script that runs once or twice every day and sends a GET request to my webserver. From there I can handle it however I see fit. The other option setting up mail from the command line to email me, but that isn't very elegant either. There has to be a better solution, right?

Comment: Are you trying to get the IP address, just so you know what one to use to try and connect, or you just need a list of changes? If the former, you just want to a DDNS solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to set up a [no-ip.org free address](http://www.no-ip.com/services/managed_dns/free_dynamic_dns.html) for that computer. No-ip.org lets you register a sub domain to *.no-ip.org that you can use to an IP to your liking. The site also offers a [tool](http://www.no-ip.com/downloads.php) that will automatically update the DNS records to your current IP. This means the registered xxx.no-ip.org address will always point to your IP address.

From no-ip.org about their tool:

> Keep your current IP address in sync with your No-IP host or domain with our Dynamic Update Client (DUC). Our dynamic DNS update client continually checks for IP address changes in the background and automatically updates the DNS at No-IP whenever it changes.

As recommended by @[LamarB](https://superuser.com/users/90419/lamar-b), dyndns.org offers a similar service.

Comment: dnydns also offers a similar service